# How to print an R object to stderr in Rcpp?

Tags: r, rcpp

I implemented a [Python-style dictionary for R](https://github.com/mkuhn/dict), but did not find a good way to raise an error when a given key does not have a value in the dictionary. Calling `stop` is easy enough, but I would like to tell the user which key has not been found by printing the R object. Right now I have:

```
Rcpp::Rcout << "Key not found: ";
Rcpp::print(key); # <-- how can I get this on stderr?
Rcpp::stop("Key error!");
```

This prints the message to stdout, but I'd rather have it on stderr. Probably I'm just missing a function that Rcpp provides?

Here's a MWE:

```
library(Rcpp)

sourceCpp(code='

#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void test(SEXP key) {
  Rcpp::print(key);
  Rcpp::Rcerr << "This does not work: " << key << std::endl;
}

/*** R
test("x")
test(c(1,2,3))
*/

')
```

Comment: You can simply use `std::cerr << "Key not found" << std::endl;`within the Rcpp code.

Comment: Have you tried the obvious, i.e. `Rcerr`?

Comment: The key point is the "Rcpp::print(key)". If I try `Rcpp::Rcerr << "Key not found: " << key << std::endl;` I get `Key not found: 0x7fafceee37b8`

Comment: I don't understand. You want to throw an error that an object was not found and than output the object that was not found. Häh?

Comment: @Roland please see my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, it seems that this hack is the only way to go. It's not very efficient, as we go back from C++ to R to get the value as a nice string.

```
library(Rcpp)

sourceCpp(code='

#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void test(SEXP key, Function generate_error) {
  std::string s = as<std::string>(generate_error(key));
  stop(s);
}

/*** R

generate_error <- function(key) {
  paste("Key not found:", capture.output(print(key)))
}

try( test("x", generate_error) )
try( test(c(1,2,3), generate_error) )
*/

')
```

Comment: I hear you, but I think this rabbit hole is deeper than you think: look at the [R's implementation of printValue](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/print.c). Of course it's bad design, that's why I'm calling it a hack right in the beginning of the answer.

Answer (score 5):

This works just fine:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::string test(std::string key) {
  Rcpp::Rcerr << "Key not found: "<< key << std::endl;
  Rcpp::stop("Key error!");
  return key;
}

/*** R
test("x")
*/
```

Output:

```
Key not found: x
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : Key error!
```

**Edit:**

OK, so you pass a SEXP that can be a single value or vector. I would suggest to cast that to a character vector:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void test(SEXP key) {
  CharacterVector key1 = as<CharacterVector>(key);
  Rcpp::Rcerr << "This does not work: " << key1 << std::endl;
}

/*** R
test(c("x", "y"))
test(1:3)
  */
```

Output:

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp('E:/temp/ttt.cpp')

> test(c("x", "y"))
This does not work: "x" "y"

> test(1:3)
This does not work: "1" "2" "3"
```

Comment: "x" isn't an R object

Comment: @yuyoyuppe And why does that matter? You could just as well define `std::string key1 = "a";` and do `Rcpp::Rcerr << "Key not found: "<< key1 << std::endl;` and this would still run.

Comment: it does matter, because I don't know in advance if x is a string, a number, a list, ... see the MWE I just added

Comment: @MichaelKuhn It's not obvious to me what your expected output is. If I pass a 1 million row data.table you want to print that to the error stream? That seems less than desirable.

Comment: It should behave like the Python dictionary, which does print out the full key (e.g. try in Python: `{}[tuple(range(1000))]`). A 1 million-row table wouldn't be a valid key, but a 1 million-item vector would. But I think it's better to have that in the error stream than not knowing which key caused the error.

Comment: yes and no: it prints kind of prints the object, but a numeric vector is converted to a string vector. This could be extremely confusing to the end user of the function :-/

Comment: @Roland Maybe just mix in a `switch` statement with the above logic, e.g. something like [this](https://gist.github.com/nathan-russell/bb15db458ca9727ba76d#file-printerror-cpp).

Comment: @MichaelKuhn and if you were expecting a number to print not as a string, then as what? In binary?

Comment: @HongOoi A numeric vector will be printed like this: `1 2 3`. A string vector shows instead: `"1" "2" "3"`

Comment: Where is this printing exactly? The `Rcerr` part won't be captured in `tryCatch`'s error bucket.

Comment: I believe tryCatch only captures the error stream when an error is thrown. Output to this stream without an error is of no concern to it because there is no condition to handle.

Answer (score 0):

[Rcpp calls Rf_PrintValue](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/9642541239f0985d0f211d106f2cdc3169806d23/inst/include/Rcpp/print.h#L26) internally. I've glanced at R source and it seems like this function is in turn implemented using `printf`s.

So, the problem is how to redirect external `printf` calls to `stderr`. Depending on your platform you have multiple options like `dup`/`freopen`/`CreatePipe` etc. Arguably, redirecting `stdout` back and forth is a hack.

Comment: It is a bit more involved, and note that [Writing R Extensions]() makes it very clear that R's _existing_ i/o facilities are to be used.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel oh I see! but what is the actual problem? `operator<<` doesn't call `printValue` for `RObject`?

Comment: `Rcpp::print()` is just one of several options. Nobody but you suggested it.  The *obvious* solution, I would surmises involves `REprintf()`.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel the question was how to `print` to stderr `SEXP` object using iostreams-like interface from `Rcpp`, so I didn't suggest using `print`. It just looks like `Rcerr` doesn't use `printValue` function under the hood, and `REprintf` obviously doesn't support `RObject`.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel [OP's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35982284/how-to-print-an-r-object-to-stderr-in-rcpp/35986479?noredirect=1#comment59626308_35986158)

Comment: I think @yuyoyuppe is right, R seems to provide only Rf_PrintValue for "pretty printing" objects, and this makes printing errors hard even in normal R: compare `message(1:3)` and `print(1:3)`.

Comment: Maybe I need to repeat what I said earlier: `REprintf()`.  If the _provided_ reporting mechanisms in a _programming library_ do not suit, maybe it is time to buckle up and just write your own helper function that does things to your specification?  And if you think you need an all-singing-all-dancing `print()` operator that prints where you want it, maybe you need to write that too.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I'm not sure why you sound so annoyed. As I wrote in the question: "Probably I'm just missing a function that Rcpp provides?" -- Rcpp and the general C interface of R are so complex that it's not obvious which functions are built-in, and which aren't.